# Number of regions in space from planes through origin

Tags: 3d

I've seen that the cake numbers give the largest number of regions that can be created by cutting 3-D space by N planes.  I have a variation on that question.  How many regions can be created by N planes that all pass through the origin (subspaces)?  In 2-D, using lines it looks like 2N regions can be created.  For 3D and planes I'm not sure, but I imagine it will be less that the cake numbers.

Comment: Yep...  $2N$.  Proof by induction:  If $N=1$:  two regions.  Each additional plane adds $2$ regions.

Comment: Given that the three coordinate planes cut $\mathbb R^3$ into eight regions (orthants), $2N$ is certainly not the right answer in three dimensions.

Comment: Thanks David, but I'm looking for the number of regions in 3D cut by planes.  I know for 3 planes the answer is 8.  It probably grows as a polynomial in N, but at a slower rate than the cake sequence.  I need to compare it to the number of vertices in the unit cube which is 2^N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first plane $p_0$ be $z=0$. Consider the plane $p'_0$ $z=1$. All partition of space with $p_0$, $p_1$,...$p_n$ will create a pattern of lines $a_1$,... $a_n$ on a plane $p'_0$ and vice versa.

For every flat piece on plane $p'_0$ there are two  subspaces: one above $p_0$ and one below. So your number is twice the $(n-1)$-th [central polygonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence):
$$
k = (n-1)^2+(n-1)+2 = n^2-n+2.
$$

Comment: I think I see this.  Every possible set of cuts by N planes sets up a set of polygonal cones with their vertex at the origin.  You have just cut all the cones facing in the z > 0 direction.  The most cones is the CPN in N-1 dimensional space.  Each cone is reflected through the origin and so we double count.  Very elegant.